# StringBuilder Java

Tags: java, строки

Как я могу передать параметр в builder.append?

Дело в том, что мне необходимо вывести мою строку, но перед этим сделать её длиной в 100.000 символов.

Мне подсказали, что можно сделать это с помощью `StringBuilder`.

Я попытался передать строку в builder.append, но компилятор выдаёт ошибку.

```java
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String text = (Poem.text);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    builder.append(text);
}
String result = builder.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Я ещё совсем новичок в программировании, буду рад любому совету!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу узнать, как передать в builder.append мою строку.

Comment: В вопрос нужно добавить информацию о том, какую ошибку вы получаете. И еще: что такое `Poem.text`?

Comment: Poem.text - это класс, в котором содержится стихотворение. Ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Comment: @Александр, если добавить куда-то поэму сто тысяч раз, что получится? А что вы делаете? А что нужно было сделать?

Comment: Какая длина вашего стихотворения?  Какой смысл выводить 100 тыс. символов в консоль?

Answer (score 0):

```
       public class Solution {
    
        static class Poem {
            static String text = "ввести любой текст ";
        }
    
        static void pr() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String text = (Poem.text);
    
    //пока строка меньше 100_000 символов
            while (builder.length() < 100_000) {
                builder.append(text);
    
            }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
            System.out.println(builder.length());
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Solution.pr();
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как быть, если текст представлен в таком формате? -   public static String text =
            "У лукоморья дуб зелёный,\n" +
                    "Златая цепь на дубе том.\n" +
                    "И днём и ночью кот учёный\n" +
                    "Всё ходит по цепи кругом.\n" +

Comment: Этот ответ не создаёт строку длиной 100000 символов. Этот ответ не отличается от вопроса, насколько я вижу.

Comment: Создаёт, я запускал этот код. Проблема в том, что у меня исходная строка представлена в другом виде.

Comment: какая разница в каком формате строка?

Comment: @Александр, так что должно получиться в результате?  Текст, который повторяется, пока его длина не составит 100 тыс. символов (включая пробелы и переносы строк)?

Comment: Или текст, дополненный пробелами до длины 100 тыс.?

Comment: Да,текст который повторяется, пока его длина не составит 100 тыс. символов.